# Adding security to Openapi after converting from SpringFox

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm converting from SpringFox to [springdoc openapi](https://springdoc.org/).  I can't figure out how to get authorization working.

I added these annotations on my config class

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My API", version = "v1"))
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "Authorization",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY,
        in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)
```

I get the authorization prompt and can enter a key, but when I click *Try It Now*->*Execute*, the Authorization header is not being sent

[image]

Is there some additional annotation I need to enable this?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the part I was missing.  I didn't post my OpenAPI definition before, but I needed to add the `security` field.  Here is my complete definition

```
@Bean
public OpenAPI nexusOpenApi() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info().title(getTitle())
                    .description(getDescription())
                    .version(getVersion())
                    .license(new License().name("(C) Copyright xxx").url("http://www.example.com")))
            .security(Collections.singletonList(new SecurityRequirement().addList("Authorization")))
            .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation());
    }
```

The name, `Authorization`, matches the name specified in the `SecurityScheme` annotation

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps others, that's all there is to it, after including the dependency in your project for `springdoc-openapi-ui`.

You can create for example a Configuration class `SwaggerConfig.java` but you don't have to, as long as you define a bean which returns the `OpenAPI` object:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI springOpenApiConfig() {
         return new OpenAPI()
            .components(new Components()
                        .addSecuritySchemes("api_key", new SecurityScheme()
                                  .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
                                  .description("Api Key access")
                                  .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                                  .name("X-API-Key")
              )          )
              .security(Arrays.asList(
                           new SecurityRequirement().addList("api_key")))
              // whatever else you need
              .info(new Info().title("Your project name")
              .description("Hello")
              .version("v1")
      }
}
```

In this example, it uses the "X-API-Key" header, so you might want to change that depending on what header name your application expects.